# Strange output from RedirectMatch

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm trying some 301 redirects in .htaccess.

I'm trying to redirect something like this:

```
http://creek.com/wines/red/greatwine
```

into

```
http://creek.com/shop/product/wines/red/greatwine
```

but I'm getting the following output

```
http://creek.com/shop/product/red/greatwine?/wines/red/greatwine
```

There are many different subdirectories under wines, so I need those to be wildcarded. I hope that makes sense.

Please see my .htaccess below.
Thanks for any help!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^creek.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://creek.com/$1 [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

RedirectMatch 301 ^/wines/(.*)/(.*)$ http://creek.com/shop/product/$1
```

Comment: Your url goes first through the rewrite than through redirect (and you can't change the order). Convert the redirect into a rewrite and place it before the other redirect rules.

Answer (score 0):

@Dan is right.

You should convert your `RedirectMatch` into a `Rewrite` and place it before your `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wines/(.*)/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://creek.com/shop/product/$1 [L,R=301]
```